# MPAndroidChart pie chart animateY initial flickering

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've set up two pie charts with almost the exact same code.

In one implementation I've made `mChart.animateX(1400);` and in the other `mChart.animateY(1400);`

When using the `animateY` there is an initial flickering where we can see all the pie chart. This does not happen when using `animateX`

Here I have an video of the flickering.
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VwP4uVeHsw)

I've tested in two devices. One running KitKat and the other Marshmallow.
I'm fetching data from a server and adding the chart dinamicaly.

Comment: So.... what sort of answers do you expect? "Oh, your youtube video is nice" ?

We don't even know whats happening there.

Comment: I thought the question was self explaining. When using `animateY` (the second graph in the video) the graph flickers. This is not the behaviour when using `animateX`. The answer I expected was one of the following. This is the expected behavior or This is a bug or You must do this ... to solve that issue. Just want to understand why that happens

Comment: Have you tried using the `nineolddroids` library? Perhaps it has to do with the SDK versions you're using. Perhaps it's device/vendor specific... You've tested this on how many phones exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Tested on 2 devices. One running Android M and the other, KitKat

Comment: Are they from different Vendors? Samsung, HTC, Sony etc ... ? Because, try different vendors as well. It's possible that it's device-specific or just vendor-specific. But it's also possible that you simply have a bug somewhere, which cannot be spotted in the `mChart.animateX(1400);` or `mChart.animateY(1400);` lines.

Comment: Yep. One Samsung and one OnePlus One

Comment: Heh, no idea (yet)... but try more devices, 2 is a very low number as it gives you either 0%, 50% or 100% reproduction rates. Try with 5 or 10 to narrow down the problem(atic devices).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure not to set any default value to your chart before setting the values coming from server. It seems like you are trying to set data to your chart twice. So, this cause an interrupted animation from first data setting, as seen in the video.

Comment: Thanks but no. I'm only setting the values once and after the server sending the date. Before I don't even have any data to display